# Transform a list of dicts to a new list of dicts with a different format

Tags: python, dictionary

What would be the best approach to transform the existing list of dict shown below to the new list of dicts also shown below?

Given:

```
data = [{'count': 3}, {'day': '2013-07-14'}, {'count': 5}, {'day': '2013-04-14'}]
```

Expected output:

```
newlist = [{'name': 'day', 'data': ['2013-07-14', '2013-04-14']}, {'name': 'count','data': [3, 5]}]
```

Comment: Your braces in `data` don't seem to be matched correctly

Comment: Hint: Start off with a `defaultdict`

Comment: Your desired data structure makes no sense. Why wouldn't you have `new_data={count:[3, 5], 'day':['2013-07-14', '2013-04-14']}` for example?

Comment: @dawg The idea is get the key name from the given data list (in this example 'day' and 'count' and assign as value to 'name' key in new dict)

Comment: The edit you made actually turns it into a different question -- from a copy to transformation. Also the expected output as listed does not appear correct.

Comment: @KenHampson It was there in the first one too if you look at the edit history.  Just formatted differently.

Comment: The data structure I suggested HAS the names of the key names. You would access it like so `dawg_dict['count'][0]` vs `user2896521_list[1]['data'][0]` to access the same element. The structure you have is not intuitive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to group your data together.  I would use a dict() for the newlist, honestly... but I'll add in the conversion to a list at the end.

Basically just iterate your list of dicts, then iterate those dicts and add them to a new dict.  Using a dict as a target is easiest since it will let you just add to the appropriate list element.  At this point, I would just stop and use the dict as your output, however to answer your question fully...

Then convert that dict back to a list of dicts in the format you are looking for.  There might be cleverer ways of doing this with dict and list comprehensions, but it might be easier this way if you are learning.

```
data = [{'count': 3}, {'day': '2013-07-14'}, {'count': 5}, {'day': '2013-04-14'}]

group=dict()
for d in data:
    for item in d:
        try:
            group[item].append(d[item])
        except KeyError:
            group[item] = [d[item]]

newlist = []
for item in group:
    newlist.append( {'name' : item, 'data' : group[item]} )
```

The contents of newlist:

```
>>> newlist
[{'data': [3, 5], 'name': 'count'}, {'data': ['2013-07-14', '2013-04-14'], 'name': 'day'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments. the data as pasted doesn't have correctly matching braces. It also has the wrong type of quote (not a normal single quote).

The question is whether you want a *shallow* or *deep* copy.

```
>>> data = [{'count': 3}, {'day': '2013-07-14'}, {'count': 5}, {'day': '2013-04-14'}]
>>> import copy
>>> datacopy = copy.deepcopy(data)
>>> print datacopy
[{'count': 3}, {'day': '2013-07-14'}, {'count': 5}, {'day': '2013-04-14'}]
>>> print id(datacopy[0])
140321178253024
>>> print id(data[0])
140321178192704
```

The calls to *id* show that the items in the 0th element are in different address locations, and therefore, true deep copies.

That's in contrast to this *shallow* copy, where the id calls return the same address:

```
>>> datacopyShallow = copy.copy(data)
>>> print datacopyShallow
[{'count': 3}, {'day': '2013-07-14'}, {'count': 5}, {'day': '2013-04-14'}]
>>> print id(data[0])
140321178192704
>>> print id(datacopyShallow[0])
140321178192704
```

**Edit:**

Note that this applies to the original question that was asked. The expected output was subsequently changed which implies that instead of a direct copy, there's actually some transformation desired, although the structure of the expected new format does not seem correct.